# What does the prefix iso- mean in "isolate"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, prefixes

My question is referring to the prefix *iso-* and its meaning in the word *isolate*. My question is, if the prefix means *equal*, how does that make sense in the word *isolate*?

Comment: 30 seconds on Google got me this:  back-formation from isolated set apart, from French isolé, from Italian isolato, from isola island, from Latin insula

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should have been *insulated,* not *isolated.* The root has undergone a distortion along the way. *Insulated* is also used, in a closely related meaning.

Answer (score 12):

The etymology of isolate is not the same as the prefix 'iso'.

> **isolated** (adj.) 
>       1763, from French isolé "isolated" (17c.) + English -ated (see -ate (2)). The French word is from Italian isolato, from Latin insulatus "made into an island," from insula "island." The French word was used at first in English (isole, also isole'd, c.1750), then after isolate became an English word, isolated became its past participle.
>
> **iso-** 
>       word-forming element meaning "equal, similar, identical; isometric," from comb. form of Greek isos "equal to, the same as" (as in isometor "like one's mother"). Used properly only with words of Greek origin; the Latin equivalent is equi- (see equi-).

Source: http://www.etymonline.com

Comment: If it was *insula* in It., why and when did it produce *isolato*?

Comment: @Frank Your request was perfectly reasonable, the site wouldn't be what it is without sources.

Comment: @Kris Was your comment ever answered? Or was it a witticism that I missed?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit The endorsement shows that it, after all, makes sense. Even I could find a satisfactory answer so far. :)

Comment: @Kris: Thanks for your comment. To clarify, do you mean that your comment of Mar 2 was answered in the Answer above? I had interpreted it as postdating the answer.

Comment: @LePressentiment: That's a matter of ordinary sound changes from Latin to Italian.